# Spring SOAP Web service - Displaying images from DB/path

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

From my understanding of SOAP, it's all about request and and response and it always outputs the response in a cryptic format (XML).

However, a fellow student told me to create a SOAP Service that displays images from a DB (or a folder with images) - just like we know from Tumblr/Pinterest/etc.

I just don't understand how that's possible - if at all?

Comment: XML isn't really cryptic. It is usually considered a very structured, human readable, format.

Answer (score 3):

I think what they mean is storing the images in a folder somewhere on the server and storing the file path to them as strings in the database. At least that's how I would do it.

You could also possibly encode the data with something like base64 and store that plus other relevant information like the content type (jpeg/gif etc) + a filename for the file to later stick together/decode to form an image.

Also, just in my personal opinion SOAP/XML is the devil, and I would personally serve the data as JSON.

Comment: I would usually say that SOAP is the devil, and REST is the better way to handle most calls.